# string not defined in atom for python code

Tags: python-3.x

[Wrote a simple program to understand better. But I don't know where it went wrong. What else packages do I need to install?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOJwU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Python 2 interpreter to run a program designed for Python 3. You have two choices:

- Change the program to reflect the differences between Python versions
- Install and set up Python 3 (you need to update the paths or run the exact python verison)

I would advise you to use Python 3.

Anyway, the Python 2 version of your program should look like that:

```
s = raw_input()

if s == "done":
    print "Done"
else:
    print "Not Done"
```

P.S. Please do not post the screenshots of the program in future. Appreciate the others and post it in text.